# Doctrine2 [Syntax Error] Error: Expected Literal, got '-'

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine2 with symfony2 and I am trying to perform a simple select query:

I want to run:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE status in (1, -1)
```

This PHP code:

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
        ->select('n')
        ->from('MyBundle:Table', 'n')
        ->where('n.status IN (1, -1)');
return $queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Gives the following exception:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 96: Error: Expected Literal, got '-'
```

This is the attribute definition within the entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $status;
```

If I use only positive numbers within the `in` argument, it will work. The exception only happens with negative numbers.

What causes this exception?

Comment: Dashes are not allowed as they could be part of an SQL injection attack.  Either get rid of the dash, or break out the negative number into a parameter.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Should do the trick :

```
$queryBuilder = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
        $queryBuilder
        ->select('n')
        ->from('MyBundle:Table', 'n')
        ->where('n.status IN (:status)')
        ->setParameter('status', array(1, -1));
```

Comment: I was wondering why you have to set a parameter and in the documentation I've found that it is to prevent SQL Injections. You can find the doc [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql)