# Doctrine SUBSTRING_INDEX extention spit an error in query builder

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to use doctrine **SUBSTRING_INDEX** extension to select all transfers that have been made from an account number by using the query below. **t.fromAccount** is a text field eg. "**Gold Current Account - 25547845965851**". Account number is after the dash.

```
  public function findTransfersByAccountNumber($accountNumber)
{
    $qb = $this->getTransferQuery()
               ->leftJoin('t.customer', 'c')
               ->where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.fromAccount, '-', -1) = :accountNumber")
               ->orderBy('t.dateCreated','DESC')
               ->setParameter('accountNumber',$accountNumber);
    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();        
}
```

But doctrine spit out this error "**[Syntax Error] line 0, col 117: Error: Expected Literal, got '-'**". Strangely if I change -1 to 1 then it runs without any error but returns nothing.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Total guess, but what if you quote the -1?

Comment: adding quote produces this error "Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on recommendation by a comment to a question 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17719558/doctrine2-syntax-error-error-expected-literal-got?rq=1,)
which states that **Dashes are not allowed as they could be part of an SQL injection attack. Either get rid of the dash, or break out the negative number into a parameter.** The below code worked as expected.

```
public function findTransfersByAccountNumber($accountNumber)
{
    return $this->getTransferQuery()
        ->leftJoin('t.customer', 'c')
        ->where("SUBSTRING_INDEX(t.fromAccount, '-', :offset) = :accountNumber")
        ->orderBy('t.dateCreated','DESC')
        ->setParameter('accountNumber',$accountNumber)
        ->setParameter('offset','-1')
        ->getQuery()->getResult();

}
```